# How do I truncate a RDS table in AWS Glue job before the data load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue as the ETL to load data to a RDS table, this is a daily snapshot table that needs to be truncated before the day's data load.

I tried  the "Preactions" parameter in DynamicFrameWriter Class but it looks like it is Redshift ONLY.

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job/#

Comment: you can try python jdbc connection to truncate the table before writing the data using Glue writer to write the data into RDS.

Comment: thanks, am getting started on glue&python. So would appreciate if you could direct me to ref doc on how to establish a python jdbc conn within a Glue job.

Comment: I think using a Lambda function is most likely the best solution to this. You can execute the DROP/TRUNCATE query in a Lambda function and then execute a Glue job once the truncate has executed. Also the connection parameters can be safely stored in the secrets manager rather than embedded in a Glue Job (unsure if Glue supports this). I have a Lambda function triggered by the drop of new CSV data to S3 which then gets ingested to RDS by Glue so this is the route I plan to take.

Answer (score 0):

```
 conn = pymysql.connect(<URL>, user=<user_name>, passwd=<password>, db=<db_name>, connect_timeout=30)
        print("mysql_connection")
        print(conn)

        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("drop table if exists <tableName>")
            conn.commit()
```